# Which architecture to choose for neural network for object recognition?

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, object-recognition

I have question about design of Neural Net.

I'm quite new to topic, but I have solid intuition about it.
I know I should use **convolutional neural network** for it.
But what existing design of net may I use? 
I want to classify some object on picture, for instance road signs.
Where should I look?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, fine-tuned convolutional neural network is a cutting edge architecture for such task.

Usually, CNN is composed of successive convolutional and pooling layers and has some fully-connected layers on the output.

I'd strongly recommend you to check out [this](http://cs231n.github.io/) link for detailed explanation.

Comment: even I don't have such mathematical background for it?

Comment: You don't really need to be proficient at math to use deep learning algorithms. Definitely, some basic math skills are required (calculus basics, vectors, matrices, optimization) but it takes only a couple of weeks (or even days) to obtain a level sufficient for using deep learning even if you're started from scratch.

Answer (score -1):

CNN is OK.

I wouldn't use tensorflow. I suggest to look at the framework caffe. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Why you would not to use tensorflow? Do you have reason for it? Or someone other has something against TensorFlow? I want to do it with TF, but I'm newbie, so any good tips are welcome

Comment: http://deeplearning4j.org/compare-dl4j-torch7-pylearn.html Look at this site. I think, there stand nearby facts.